# Deriving a general formula for the number of onto functions from the given theorem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

I want to use this:

> Let $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_n$ be $n$ sets in a universe $U$ of $N$ elements. Let $S_1 = \sum_jN(A_j), \ S_2 = \sum_{i, j}N(A_iA_j), \ldots, S_k = \sum N(A_{j_1}A_{j_2\ldots A_{j_k}}), \ldots, S_n = N(A_1A_2\ldots A_n)$

> Then $$ N(\overline A_1\overline A_2\ldots \overline A_n) = N(U) - S_1 + S_2 - S_3 + \ldots + (-1)^kS_k+ \ldots + (-1)^nS_n$$

to derive this:

> The number of onto functions $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, r\} \to \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$ is $$\sum_{j=0}^n\binom nj(-1)^j(n - j)^r$$.

So,

Let $S_0 = N(U).$ Then $$N(U) - S_1 + S_2 - S_3 + \ldots + (-1)^kS_k+ \ldots + (-1)^nS_n \\ = \sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^kS_k \\ = \sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\sum N(A_{j_1}A_{j_2\ldots A_{j_k}}) \\  = \sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k \binom nkN(A_{j_1}A_{j_2\ldots A_{j_k}}) \\ = \sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k \binom nkN(A_{j_k})$$

Now let $A_{j_k}$ be the set of functions that miss $k$ elements.  Then $N(A_{j_k})$ is the number of such functions which is given by $(n - k)^r.$

The derivation above seems to work iff $N(A_{j_1}A_{j_2\ldots A_{j_k}}) = N(A_{j_k})$ which I am not sure is true. If so, how do we prove that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $N(A_{j_k})$ has $(n-1)^r$ because you are missing just $1$ element. Instead, $N(A_{j_1}A_{j_2}\cdots A_{j_k})$ is $(n-k)^r$ because you are missing now $k$ elements instead. They are not equal is just that the last equality is not true.

Comment: How do we know $A_{j_1}A_{j_2}\cdots A_{j_k}$ is a set of functions missing $k$ elements? I mean how do we define $A_{j_i}$ for that to be true?

Comment: Cause this seems to be the intersection. If $A_{x}$ is the functions that miss $x$ and $A_y$ the ones that miss $y$ then $A_x\cap A_y$ are the ones that miss $x$ and $y$ (so two elements).

Comment: I forgot to ask. Shouldn't the functions that miss $x, y$ be $A_x \cup A_y$? I mean, for example, $\{1\} \cap \{2\} = \emptyset,$ but $\{1\} \cup \{2\} = \{1, 2\}.$ Can you elaborate on $A_x \cap A_y$ and give a small example? Thanks.

Comment: No. $A_x\cup A_y$ reads like: You miss $x$ **or** you miss $y.$ while $A_x\cap A_y$ reads: You miss $x$ **and ** $y.$ You are taking $A_1\cap A_2$ not $\{1\}\cap \{2\}.$

Comment: Consider $f: \{1, 2\} \to \{a, b\}$ with $X = \{(1, a), (2, a)\}$ and $Y = \{(1, b), (2, b)\}$. The functions in $X$ miss $b$ and the functions in $Y$ miss $a$, but $X \cap Y = \emptyset?$

Comment: So $X$ is a function and $Y$ is another function. We are not taking the intersection on the functions, we are taking the intersection on functions which miss $a$ and $b.$ Of course, if $n=2$ they number of functions that avoid elements $a$ and $b$ is $0.$

Comment: One last question, how are you defining $A_{j_i}$?

Comment: $A_{j_i}=\{f:[r]\longrightarrow [n]: j_i\text{ is not in the image of }f\}$